# Showing a simple text to the user when the user pays from my site

Tags: php, paypal

I have two `php` file: 1- `get.php` 2- `send.php`. Consider the user clicks on the buy button and requests  to connect in the payment gateway page. the `send.php` for the user is as follows:

```
     <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { 
$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];          
function send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"api=$api&amount=$amount&redirect=$redirect");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $res;
            }
            $url = 'http://payment.com/payment-test/gateway-send';
            $api = 'adxcv-zzadq-polkjsad-opp13opoz-1sdf455aadzmck1244567';
            $amount = 1000;
            $redirect = urlencode('http://localhost/get.php');
            $result = send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect);
            if($result > 0 && is_numeric($result)){
            $go = "http://payment.com/payment-test/gateway-$result";
    //save the username and the get_id in a table.        
    header("Location: $go");
            }}
        esle {echo "found an error in connecting to payment gateway";} ?>
```

Now, the user goes to the payment gateway page and he does operation payment successfully. Now the payment gateway page from the bank sends `trans_id` and `id_get` to the `get.php` file and the `get.php` file is as follows:

```
    function get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"api=$api&id_get=$id_get&trans_id=$trans_id");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
    }
    $url = 'http://payment.com/payment-test/gateway-result-second';
    $api = 'adxcv-zzadq-polkjsad-opp13opoz-1sdf455aadzmck1244567';
    $trans_id = $_POST['trans_id'];
    $id_get = $_POST['id_get'];
    $result = get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get);
    if($result == '1') { 
//find the `$id_get`value in the table and put the `trans_id` within the same raw that the id_get is
echo "successfully"; }
    else {echo "Unsuccessfully";}
```

The problem in the `get.php`is the `echo` does not know that sends the messages to which user.And If I use the session in the top of the `get.php`file, as the result the `session_start()` gets a session from the payment gateway website.

Comment: WHY DONT U INSERT TRANS ID IN DB IN SEND.PHP PAGE AND WHEN IN GET.PHP MATCH TRANSID WITH UID

Comment: Because the `trans_id` there is no in `send.php` and it be sent in `get.php` file to verify the transaction.

Comment: so in the redirect url in get.php append some identifier ..

Comment: @n01ze, My question was something else. Does be sent in the `get.php` file the `successfully` or the `unsuccessfully` messages to the user that had purchased?